# How do I move a control to the center of a screen at runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I have a control (it's a label) of varying size. I want to recenter it in the form each time it changes (horizontally centered, not vertically). How would I do that programmatically?

Comment: You may try Control.Docking property.

Comment: pseudocode: Center horizontally: Label.X = (form.Width - label.Width)/2; Center vertically: Label.Y = (form.Height - label.Height) / 2;  .. To do it vertically, which you didn't ask about, this works if the form is the parent, otherwise you'd have to use the Location property to set the top-left Point of the control.

Comment: @JimSchubert: Please don't put answers in comments.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Is my comment an answer when the question has already been answered and I use pseudocode instead of C#/winforms-specific code?  As a comment or an answer, it is there for future reference and that's what StackOverflow is about.  I double-checked the FAQ and there's nothing about not adding alternatives in comments instead of answers.

Comment: @JimSchubert: Yes, it's an answer. Comments are intended for *clarifying the question* and participating in short discussion that's relevant to the question. They are not intended to provide answers, including short answers such as yours. There are numerous posts on meta about this topic. StackOverflow is about making information available in a peer-reviewed manner, not simply putting information "out there"; comments cannot be downvoted. If you want to help the OP, post an answer. If you feel it would be too short, wait for someone else.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Thanks for putting me straight! I will post short answers as answers in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
YourLabel.Left = (YourForm.Width / 2) - (YourLabel.Width / 2);
```

If you want this to be adjusted every time the form dimensions change, just utilize the `Form.Resize` event.

Comment: Dont do it programmatically just use the Docking property of the label to centre it.

Comment: Make sure you check for negative values before you set YourLabel.Left to avoid run-time errors.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I don't believe that'll give the OP the desired results.  Check out the `DockStyle` enum (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle.aspx).  There are no constants for centering the control in its parent.

Comment: Er, there is nothing wrong with negative values for `Left` (or `Top`, for that matter). It's `Width` and `Height` that must be >=0

Comment: In relation to @JeremyThompson's comment, it *may* work if the label is set to autosize (as that'll override the dock's sizing), but I don't believe so (I think it'll just be in the top left corner).

Comment: @AdamRobinson You are absolutely correct.  Just tested it.  The `Left` property absolutely can be a negative value.  Good catch.

Answer (score 4):

No code required: AutoSize = False, TextAlign = TopCenter.  Make it as big as you'll allow it to get.  Anchor to the right is optional.

Comment: Doesn't work very nicely - just like my RAD attempt:( edit without the Right Anchor it is actually ok.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest Way to center any component. might be helpful for someone. Right click Project -> Add -> Class

Update that class with below code.

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static void center(this Control component)
    {
        float compWidth = component.Width;
        float parentWidth = component.Parent.Width;
        float middled = (parentWidth / 2) - (compWidth / 2);

        component.Left = Convert.ToInt32(middled);
    }
}
```

and then you can middle any component. you can use on any component like this

```
MyLabel.center();
MyPanel.center();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I stand corrected - thanks guys.

Here is a workaround to do it without code using RAD (design time). **Note I would go with @Shark's answer as I dont think this will achieve the result your after but here it is:**

- Drop a button in the form
- Set its Text as the text in the label
- Size button to fit the text
- In the buttons properties "FlatStlye =Flat"
- In the buttons properties, expand Flat Appearance and set Border Size= 0
- Now set the Anchor to Left and Right